# Getting sum of a column on a specific condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sum, aggregate

Here is my table's columns:

- Id (int)
- A (int)
- B (int)

I want to calculate a sum by the following specific condition using T-SQL:

- if column B is not null add its value to sum
- if column B is null add value of column A to sum

How can I calculate the sum without updating the original data in an efficient way?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please try with my answer.

Comment: Though provided answer may help you,you will need to improve question going forward.please check here on how to improve question..https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use sum with case when. Try like this,

```
SELECT sum(CASE 
            WHEN B IS NOT NULL
                THEN B
            ELSE A
            END)
FROM Mytable
```